# Latex List of Figures

Tags: latex, pdflatex

So i'm trying to hide the label in my cover image.

```
>\begin{figure}        
>\center        
>\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{universidade}        
>\caption* {Mycaption}        
>\end {figure}
```

This way it's not labeling the figure but its not showing on the list of figures
Help please ;D

Answer (score 0):

You can give the caption package the option `labelformat=empty` to suppress the Figure 1 etc. labelling:

```
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
```

You can use square brackets to specify the description for the figure list, and curly brackets for the actual figure caption. So I think you should be able to do the following to supress the caption but still have an entry in the figure list:

```
\begin{figure}        
\center        
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{universidade}        
\caption[Mycaption]{}        
\end {figure}
```

Comment: But using that package it will apply to all document, and i just want it to apply to this particular case.

Comment: Ah, sorry, that wasn't clear from the question. I'm not sure how to achieve that. If you don't use the empty labelformat option you will have a "Figure x" in the caption.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options, depending on what yo're after exactly:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\setcounter{topnumber}{3}% Just for this example
\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
  \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{Example image A}%
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=4\baselineskip]{example-image-a}

  Example image A
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\protect\numberline{}Example image B}%
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=4\baselineskip]{example-image-b}

  Example image B
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=4\baselineskip]{example-image-c}
  \caption{Example image C}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The figure caption is added using `\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{<caption>}`, where `<caption>` can either contain a blank `\numberline{}`, or just the regular caption. The above example shows the usage of either.

It would also be possible to have no label shows in the image, but have a numbered entry in the LoF using [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption). But it would seem strange to have a numbered entry in the LoF and an unnumbered figure.