# How to extract a List of Figures from knitr/latex pdf output and load it into R?

Tags: r, latex, extract, knitr

Is there an expedient way to extract and load into R a List of Figures that `knitr` and `latex` have created in a PDF document?

My PDF has scores of figures; they are sorely in need of being tracked and organized, which the List of Figures helps do. But having the List in R would help in many ways.

Snipping the List from the PDF, pasting it into Excel, and working with that worksheet is one arduous route, but it would be quicker and smoother if it were possible to locate the List of Figures and load it directly (more or less) into R.  The knitting process creates many files and perhaps the List lurks within one of them?

Here is a small example simply to create a List of Figures, borrowed from [a question on hiding captions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325648/latex-list-of-figures)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\setcounter{topnumber}{3}% Just for this example
\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
  \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{Example image A}%
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=4\baselineskip]{example-image-a}

  Example image A
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\protect\numberline{}Example image B}%
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=4\baselineskip]{example-image-b}

  Example image B
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=4\baselineskip]{example-image-c}
  \caption{Example image C}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could take a look into `filename.lof`. Is this what you are looking for? If not, a description of the desired output would be helpful (do you need the captions only or with pagenumber; strucutre of the data etc.). There might be a ways to do this with `knitr` hooks.

Comment: @hrbmstr - I don't need page numbers, just the listing so I can compare it to my directory listing (and see which images have been put in and which have not).  My limited skills don't extend to plot knitr hooks; how would that work?

Comment: @user2706559 - no page numbers needed.  I would simply like a vector of the captions, if that can be had from filename.lof.  How do I find that file?

Comment: `filename.lof` should be in your working directory after compiling. If not, please provide some details on how you compile the document.

Comment: @user2706569.  Yes, my .lof is there.  How do I open it or how can R read its contents?  Sorry, if these questions are so basic.

Comment: You can read it with `readLines(con = "filename.lof")`. Then comes the dirty work of getting rid of all the ugly LaTeX stuff. `grep` and other functions that work with regular expressions are the way to go, but that's not one of my strenghts  … good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As page numbers are not required, it is enough to save `fig.cap` from each chunk.

This can be done using a chunk hook that saves `options$fig.cap` in a global variable and saves this variable to a file at the end of the knitting process.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<setup>>=
library(knitr)

figureCaptions <- c()

knit_hooks$set(listit = function(before, options, envir) {
  if (!before) figureCaptions <<- c(figureCaptions, options$fig.cap)
})

<<fig.cap = "First one", listit = TRUE>>=
plot(1)
@

<<fig.cap = "Second one", listit = TRUE>>=
plot(rnorm(10))
@

<<final>>=
save(figureCaptions, file = "figureCaptions.RData")
@

\end{document}
```

It should be better to save the caption only after the chunk has been evaluated (`if (!before)`) in order to avoid problems with [eval.after](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/).

To access the captions afterwards, use `load("figureCaptions.RData")`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: true
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
gen_lof <- TRUE

if (gen_lof) {

  unlink("/tmp/figures.csv")

  cat("pdf_name,output_path,caption,subcaption\n",
      file="/tmp/figures.csv", append=TRUE)

  knitr::knit_hooks$set(plot=function(x, opt) {
    cat(x, ",",
        opt$fig.path, ",",
        opt$fig.cap, ",",
        opt$fig.scap, "\n", 
        sep="", file="/tmp/figures.csv", append=TRUE)
  })

}
```
````

I slightly modified the default RStudio example knitr doc to add two figures with names and captions.

Set `gen_lof` to FALSE for your normal PDF creation (using a hook mean having to knit once for the full output PDF and once again for just the CSV of figures). Set it to `TRUE` and knit it to get an list of figures output (wherever you want, I just used that filename for convenience) file that will look like:

```
pdf_name,output_path,caption,subcaption
Untitled_files/figure-latex/cars-1.pdf,Untitled_files/figure-latex/,lines cars,
Untitled_files/figure-latex/pressure-1.pdf,Untitled_files/figure-latex/,points cars,
```

While they may have `pdf` for an output type, it should not be too much trouble to do a 1:1 comparison.

You also have access to all the knitr chunk options this way. i.e.:

```
aniopts autodep background cache cache.lazy cache.path 
cache.rebuild cache.vars child code collapse comment 
crop dependson dev dev.args dpi echo engine error eval 
external 

fig.align fig.cap fig.cur fig.env fig.ext fig.height 
fig.keep fig.lp fig.num fig.path fig.pos fig.retina 
fig.scap fig.show fig.subcap fig.width 

highlight include interval label message out.extra 
out.height out.height.px out.width out.width.px 
params.src prompt purl ref.label render results 
sanitize size split strip.white tidy tidy.opts warning
```

(I separated out the "fig" specific options on purpose).

The use of a variable to trigger generation means you can code up parameterized knitr workflows to do one gen to get figures and then another to get the final PDF.

Others may have more optimal ways.